# VLANs on a wireless network

Tags: vlan, wireless

What are the common methods to have VLANs on a wireless network through profiles ?

Scenario :

access points ==> wireless controller ==> core switch ==> UTM

there is 3 main profiles for users to access Wireless network , Managers , Users

and Guests .

so basically we need every profile from the mentioned above to be on separate VLAN .

If it can't be done , what are the other scenarios we can adopt to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, each group has its own SSID, and the SSIDs are mapped to VLANs in the controller. You can have different authentication methods for each SSID.

Comment: Yes , the SSIDs are mapped to VLANs , But we want to be able to  route  users  traffic through different WAN Gateways and apply different Firewall rules on them ?

Comment: That depends on your wired portion of your network, specifically your gateway router(s).  If you provide a network diagram and model numbers, we can give you more details.

Comment: I marked answered because the key word for the whole scenario was the word "mapped" , thanks @Ron

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Mr. Trunk said:

Assuming your WiFi uses WPA2 enterprise, you'd have some kind of authentication server that would authenticate (or deny access) centrally, and communicate settings such as the IP address to be assigned to a station to the access point.

I haven't read into the underlying 802.11 standard (I think it's 11x) deeply enough, but my impression was that also things like routes to be set up can be communicated.

Anyway, with wpa2 enterprise, the network is already segregated, and users can't read the traffic of other users on the same network, and vlan tagging should be doable on addresses alone in your access point